# Making zoomable custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem: I don't know how to make my `layout` zoomable. I found some tricks to solve this for `ImageView`, or `Bitmap`, or `Drawable`, or something similar, but not for `layout`. I want to put an array of custom views (in fact in's just a rectangles, I override `onDraw`). Is there some ways to resolve this problem (I just don't want to reinvent the wheel) or I need to do everything by myself? Maybe somewho made such a thing? I tried to do some things with `ScaleGestureDetector`, but failed. My code is shown below

```
public class Seat extends View {

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private float mWidth;
    private float mHeight;

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    public static final int ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK  = 0xff00;
    public static final int ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT = 8;

    // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    private boolean checked = false;
    private boolean reserved = false;
    private Place place;

    public Seat(PlacesActivity context, Place place) {
        super(context);
        setOnClickListener(new OnSeatClickListener(context));
        if (place.getReservation() != 1 || place.getStatus() != 1) {
            reserved = true;
        }
        this.place = place;
        this.mPosX = place.getX();
        this.mPosY = place.getY();

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) mWidth, (int) mHeight);
        params.leftMargin = (int) mPosX;
        params.topMargin = (int) mPosY;
        setLayoutParams(params);
        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) getParent();

        Place place = (Place) getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            Seat seat = (Seat) parent.getChildAt(i);
            Place placeToCompare = (Place) seat.getTag();
            if (place.getId() == placeToCompare.getId()) {
                parent.removeViewAt(i);
                parent.addView(this, i, params);
            }
        }

        if (reserved)
            canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        else if (checked)
            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    public void setChecked() {
        checked = true;
    }

    public void setUnchecked() {
        checked = false;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setReserved() {
        reserved = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;
                    mWidth *= mScaleFactor;
                    mHeight *= mScaleFactor;

                    invalidate();
                }

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private class OnSeatClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        private PlacesActivity context;

        public OnSeatClickListener(PlacesActivity context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!reserved) {
                Seat seat = (Seat) view;
                seat.checked = !seat.checked;
                view.invalidate();
                Place place = (Place) view.getTag();
                context.changeSeatState(place);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Place " + place.getPlace() + " row " + place.getRow(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 2.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a class of view, my layout that I want to zoom containing some of this views. I tried to apply `ScaleGestureDetector`, but also failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have made custom layout... and its zoom properly ...I have also achieved the scrolling but its not that good ... I am working on it .. Here i share my code for you . It will help you lot and if u make better scrolling than me ....then let me know ...

here it is

```
    public class ZoomLayout extends RelativeLayout implements OnDoubleTapListener, OnGestureListener{


//ScalingFactor i.e. Amount of Zoom
static float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;

// Maximum and Minimum Zoom
private static float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
private static float MAX_ZOOM = 2.0f;

//Different Operation to be used 
    private final int NONE_OPERATION=0;
    private final int DRAG_OPERATION=1;
    private final int ZOOM_OPERATION=2;
    private float mWidth= 1280;
    private float mHeight=800; 

// Mode to select the operation
    private int mode;

//Track X and Y coordinate of the finger when it first touches the screen
    private float mInitialX = 0f;
    private float mInitialY = 0f;

// Track the Bound of the Image after zoom to calculate the offset  
static Rect mClipBound;

// mDetector to detect the scaleGesture for the pinch Zoom  
private ScaleGestureDetector mDetector;

// mDoubleTapDetector to detect the double tap 
private GestureDetector mDoubleTapDetector;

//Pivot point for Scaling
static float gx=0,gy=0;

boolean mdrag=false,mZoom=false;

public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mClipBound = new Rect();
        // Intialize ScaleGestureDetector
        mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ZoomListener());
        mDoubleTapDetector = new GestureDetector(context,this);
        mDoubleTapDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }


    public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mClipBound = new Rect();
        // Intialize ScaleGestureDetector
        mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ZoomListener());
        mDoubleTapDetector = new GestureDetector(context,this);
        mDoubleTapDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // Handles all type of motion-events possible
        switch(event.getAction() ) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Event occurs when the first finger is pressed on the Screen

            Log.d("ZoomPrint", "Event: Action_Down " );
            mInitialX = event.getX();
            mInitialY = event.getY();

        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            //Event occurs when the second finger is pressed down

            Log.d("ZoomPrint", "Event: Action_Pointer_Down " );
            // If second finger is pressed on the screen with the first set the Mode to Zoom operation
            mode=ZOOM_OPERATION;

            break;  
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            Log.d("ZoomPrint", "Event: Action_Pointer_UP " );
            mdrag=true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            //Event occurs when all the finger are taken of the screen
            Log.d("ZoomPrint", "Event: Action_UP " );
            //If all the fingers are taken up there will be no operation 
            mode = NONE_OPERATION;
            mdrag=false;

            break;  


        }
        // give the event to the mDetector to get the scaling Factor
            mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);


        // give the event to the mDoubleTapDetector for the doubleTap 
            mDoubleTapDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if(!mdrag)
            invalidate();

    return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        onTouchEvent(ev);
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    //  return true;
    }







    @Override
    public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {
        return super.invalidateChildInParent(location, dirty);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        int count = getChildCount();
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i); 
            if(child.getVisibility()!=GONE){
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
                child.layout(
                    (int)(params.leftMargin ), 
                    (int)(params.topMargin ), 
                    (int)((params.leftMargin + child.getMeasuredWidth()) ), 
                    (int)((params.topMargin + child.getMeasuredHeight())) 
                    );
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //Save the canvas to set the scaling factor returned from detector
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);

        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,gx,gy);     

        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        mClipBound = canvas.getClipBounds();

          canvas.restore();
    }



    private class ZoomListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {


            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                // getting the scaleFactor from the detector
                mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();              // gives the scaling factor from the previous scaling to the current
            //  Log.d("ZoomPrint", "detector scaling Factor" + mScaleFactor);

                gx = detector.getFocusX();
                gy = detector.getFocusY();
                // Limit the scale factor in the MIN and MAX bound
                mScaleFactor= Math.max(Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM),MIN_ZOOM);
            //  Log.d("ZoomPrint", "Bounded scaling Factor" + mScaleFactor);

                /*//Force canvas to redraw itself only if the one event is to happen (say Zooming only ) else do not invalidate here for multi operations
                   As what we de for scrolling or panning will not reflect here. So we will add this in onDraw method 
                invalidate();*/
                 // Here we are only zooming so invalidate has to be done
            //  invalidate();
             //  requestLayout();

                // we have handle the onScale 
                return true;
            }



        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

        // Make the mScaleFactor to its normal value
            if(mScaleFactor>1.0f)
            {
                    mScaleFactor=1.0f;
            }
        // Force the canvas to redraw itself again as the changes has been occured.
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        //  Log.d("ZoomPrint", "OnDoubleTapEvent");
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        //  Log.d("ZoomPrint", "OnSingleTap");
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }


     @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                    float distanceX, float distanceY) {

                    int distX= (int) distanceX, distY =(int) distanceY;

        //Log.d("Print"," X " + this.mClipBound.left +" Y " + this.mClipBound.right + " b "+ this.mClipBound.bottom + " g" + this.mClipBound.top) ;

        Log.d("Print", "Scroll X " + distanceX + " Y " + distanceY);    

                if(this.mClipBound.left<=0)
                    this.scrollTo(-280, 0);
                else if(this.mClipBound.top<=0)
                    this.scrollTo(0, -250);
                    else if (this.mClipBound.right>=1047)
                        this.scrollTo(280, 0);
                    else if (this.mClipBound.bottom>=800)
                        this.scrollTo(0, 250);
                    else
                    this.scrollBy((int)distanceX,(int)distanceY);


                    return true;

            }


        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Comment the code in onScroll Method to get the zoom property. Scrolling is hardcoded because of requirement. I am finding way for proper scrolling let see...